# How do I preserve the programs I install and changes I make to a LiveUSB session?

Tags: live-usb, default-programs

I have made a LiveUSB Ubuntu version 12, booted it up. Works fine.

The problem is, I'm not allowed to install it onto someone *else's* computer, but I'm fine with a USB. I know that if I install any kind of program onto it, all changes will be erased after I shutdown/restart.

**My Question:** Is there *any* way of keeping programs/changes you've made on a LiveUSB?

Comment: Create it with a persistence partition, and yes.  You'd have to do that via either unetbootin or the usb disk creator

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this article https://wiki.ubuntu.com/LiveUsbPendrivePersistent/

Comment: Thanks! I'll try that! But can you do it from the liveusb?

Comment: Not sure but I have a feeling you can't.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.